# Jsoup: check if Element is before another (sorting)?

Tags: jsoup

I need to parse the HTML text twice and collect different elements. In my first parse I collect them with e.g.

```
    final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlStr.getContent());
    ArrayList<Element> collectEls=new ArrayList<>();
    final Elements referenceElements = doc.select("[data-coll='first-pass']");
    // some more  logic...
    referenceElements.forEach(el -> collectEls.add(el));
```

and in a second round something like

```
    final Elements referenceElements = doc.select("[data-coll='second-pass']");
    // some more  logic...
    referenceElements.forEach(el -> collectEls.add(el));
```

I canNOT collect them in one single pass. The algorithm would be far to complex. I need to sort `referenceElements` depending on their position in the HTML text, i.e. something like

```
referenceElements.sort((el1,el2) -> el1.compareTo(el2)); //would return true if el1 appears BEFORE el2
```

Honestly I have no clue how to compare them. I only found the `before` method but this is for inserting and doesn't perform any kind of checks. For the sake of example I would expect that `el1` and `el2` are distinct, i.e. no overlapping in sense one is the child of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a working Java compiler here, but I think you can start figuring it out using this information:

1. Before you parse, turn on tracking positions of HTML nodes: `setTrackPosition` https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#setTrackPosition(boolean)
2. use the `endSourceRange` method of Element to get the positoin of the closing HTML tag of your element in order to compare it to the other element's closing tag position. See https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#endSourceRange()

Comment: Thx for the hint which seems quite useful. The easiest would than to use from the Range the `end()` method and compare `pos -> lineNumber -> columnNumber`. Or you think differently?